How to calculate GUI used memory widget value?
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
to display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
GUI = Graphical User Interface
GUI used memory = see widget image below.

.
2nd method to display used memeory = 2211 MB = 2.2 GB
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31782        2211       25621        1288        3949       27839
Swap:           2047           0        2047

MemoryUsed_b=$(free -b |awk '(NR==2)' |awk '{print $3}')
echo $MemoryUsed_b
.
3rd method to display used memeory
cat /proc/meminfo
grep 'VmallocUsed' /proc/meminfo 
VmallocUsed:       39720 kB
MEM_VmallocUsed_b=$(awk '/VmallocUsed/ {printf( "%d\n", $2 * 1024 )}' /proc/meminfo) 
echo $MEM_VmallocUsed_b  
40722432

MEM_VmallocUsed_k=$(awk '/VmallocUsed/ {printf( "%d\n", $2 * 1    )}' /proc/meminfo) 
echo $MEM_VmallocUsed_k  
39736  

MEM_VmallocUsed_m=$(awk '/VmallocUsed/ {printf( "%d\n", $2 / 1024 )}' /proc/meminfo) 
echo $MEM_VmallocUsed_m  
38

MEM_VmallocUsed_g=$(awk '/VmallocUsed/ {printf( "%.3f\n", $2 / 1024 / 1024 )}' /proc/meminfo) 
echo $MEM_VmallocUsed_g  
0.038

summary, 3 displays of used memory: 
GUI used memory widget value = 3.9 GiB
            free used memory = 2.2 GiB
                 VmallocUsed = 0.039176 Gigabytes

How to calculate GUI used memory widget value?
How is it calculated?
3.9 GiB in above example.
--
